Chart Image is not saving in php using libchart library
I am using libchart to create a line graph and want to save in a location. It's showing the graph in portal but not saving the chart as images. below are the sample core.
<?php
include "libchart/classes/libchart.php";
header("Content-type: image/png");
$chart = new LineChart();

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","****","****","*******");

    
    $result1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT mno,trx_time, (res_200 * 100)/req_count AS success FROM mno_airtime_data_his WHERE mno='GP' ORDER BY trx_time DESC LIMIT 10;");
$serie1 = new XYDataSet();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
      {
     $serie1->addPoint(new Point($row['trx_time'], $row['success']));
     $name=$row['mno'];

      };

    $dataSet = new XYSeriesDataSet();
    $dataSet->addSerie("$name", $serie1);
    $chart->setDataSet($dataSet);

    $chart->setTitle("bKash MNO AIrtime Success Status(%)");
    $chart->getPlot()->setGraphCaptionRatio(0.62);
    $chart->render();
    $chart->render("GP.png");
?>

